# How to only change child classes with css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="level1">
        <div class="level2">
            <div class="level3"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="level4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="level4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
.level1 .level4 {
    width: 90px
}

.level4 {
    width:50px
}
```

I only want to change level4 if it is any child under level1 do mater how deep it is as long as it is a child of level1. How to change a specific class as long as it is somewhere under another class? Is that possible?

Comment: Are you saying your CSS rule `.level1 .level4` isn't working? Also you have a typo in `width 50px (missing the colon)`

Comment: Ya sorry. i just mocked up that code quick just as an example. The other code is too big to show. Also like I said it could be at any depth of nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should have it already.

`.level1 .level4 { ... }` will only apply to `class="level4"` when `class="level1"` appears in a parent. Just `.level4` will always apply to `class="level4"`.

---

Edit: Didn't realize it but your CSS is in the wrong order. CSS loads in order so `width: 50` overrides `width: 90`.

Comment: The only bad thing is it could be a level8. Like I said it could be at any depth of nested classes.

Comment: It doesn't matter https://plnkr.co/edit/ygyQ5BtELRFKjG5xDQrk?p=preview. Your problem is that you're loading your css backwards.

Comment: CSS is loaded in order, so your `width: 50;` overrides your `width: 90px`. Inspect the element in the browser. You will see both styles have applied to your element, but one is crossed out because it was overridden.

Answer (score -1):

Noticed in your html you wrapped the .level4 in another div

```
<div>
    <div class="level4"></div>
</div>
```

This makes the div parent of .level4 and .level1 grand parent of .level4. Therefore to style .level4 in class .level1 would be

```
.level1 div .level4 {
    Width: 90px;
 }
```

Or you might as well just remove the empty div and have just

```
<div class="level1">
    <!-- other diva-->
    <div class="level4"></div>
</div>
```

And then use

```
.level1 .level4 {
    Your style
}
```

Or you can as well just style .level4 if you not using the class anywhere else

Hope you get how this works